# How to install torrent client on linux in shared servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, mysql, bittorrent

I am using "namecheap.com" stellar hosting with Linux OS, installed on shared servers.
It has also Apache, MySQL and PHP preinstalled. I am trying to install uTorrent using terminal with the help of a tutorial. This tutorial contains commands for Ubuntu OS like sudo, /opt etc" these commands don't work in the terminal on my side. I don't know why it is happening. I asked an expert he said "sudo" command is used for super user do and you don't have root access so can't use this command. Due to shared hosting you can't use this command.

At the end. Can anyone help me to install torrent client on shared servers.

Comment: This is one of those cases where you're asking to do something that is explicitly against the provider's Terms of Service, isn't it.

Comment: They said you can install a torrent client. Consult to an IT expert. If you feel better I can give you access to my PC via RDP to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are following the steps for the right version of Linux. Distributions based on RHEL and Debian have different package managers by default, and some of the directory structures might be different too.